# C# restart a while loop in the middle

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that i want to restart if a condition is false, in my case.  It is because i'm checking if a ip is valid and if it is then run the whole loop normal and if not i need it to restart from the start again at that point. I can't use a break and i dont want to use a goto. What is your sugestions?

This is my code, where i want to restart my while loop.

```
while (calculateAgain == "y")
{
    Console.Write("Your ip here: ");
    string ip = Console.ReadLine();

    IpValidation(ip);
    if (IpValidation(ip) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ugyldig IP og eller Subnet mask!\n");
        // goto or break
    }
```

After this my code runs on a lot...
Tell me some solutions to this other than goto.

Comment: Try `continue` if you want the loop to continue from the top.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the word `continue`

```
    if (IpValidation(ip) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ugyldig IP og eller Subnet mask!\n");
        continue;
    }
```

This will skip the rest and go to the top of your loop.

Comment: Remember case-sensitivity: `continue` is the right one.

Comment: It worked! I tried this before, but it didnt work, then i found out that i had more than 1 break and changed them all...And voula

Comment: Stupid phone auto uppercased it :(

Answer (score 3):

There is the continue statement. If it will be hit it will skip back to the start of the loop.

```
while (calculateAgain == "y")
{
    // ...
    if (IpValidation(ip) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ugyldig IP og eller Subnet mask!\n");
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("This will not be executed when continue is called");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on two ways, (by using break or continue) break will exit the loop completely, `continue` will just skip the current iteration.

So by reading your question. You need to use `continue` here, so your example might look like this:

```
while (calculateAgain == "y")
{
    Console.Write("Your ip here: ");
    string ip = Console.ReadLine();

    IpValidation(ip);
    if (IpValidation(ip) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ugyldig IP og eller Subnet mask!\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

This above means, for condition `if (IpValidation(ip) == false)` code below will be skiped (will never be executed) if condition is satisfied

Comment: Remember case-sensitivity: `continue` is the right one.